# netplan apply breaks bonding

Tags: linux, bonding, systemd-networkd

Whenever I change my Network configuration on my Ubuntu 18.04 Server and apply it using `netplan apply` command, the bonding interface is no longer usable. While the IPs are correct, there is simply no communication possible. When I checked in `/proc/net/bonding/bond0` I can see, that the MII Status of all Interfaces is down. So what I have to do is delete the bonding and then `netplan apply` again which recreates it and considers everything Up again.

Is there any way, this can be done atuomatically and in a non-hacky way? This also happened when livepatch tried to apply some patches and reloaded the Network Config afterwards, leaving the server in an unusable state.